# Why was the masked man the same height as Minato?

Tags: naruto

Tobi/Madara aka the masked man was revealed to be

> Obito Uchiha.

This was revealed in the Fourth Great Ninja War but I cannot how the masked man could control the nine tails? At that time, Kakashi, Guy and his other peers were 15 years old more or less, he should also be around that age. Why do we see that the masked man is around Minato's height?
Note: Minato was at this time a full grown adult in his 20s.

Even for a very skilled shinobi, I believe it's impossible to learn so much in just 2 years. Obito was about 13 and a mediocre ninja when he was presumed dead in Konoha and encountered Madara. Now, I know many of you might say that he was taught by **Madara** but at that time Madara was himself and his 80s, very weak, and his life was attached to the Gedo statue. Now in the battle between the masked man and Minato we clearly see that when Minato hits the rasengan to the masked man a whitish DNA sort of thing drips from his arm. That could have been Obito's senju DNA as his original right body was crushed but now I couldn't agree to this because of the first paragraph. Perhaps I am missing something else.

Comment: Controlling the Kyubi requires intense Sharingan power. Age isn't a factor in such conditions. Also, height difference doesn't support anything. The reason Obito was taller is (most probably) because of the fact that he was older than Kakashi. And I wouldn't underestimate Madara's capabilities even though he was old. After all, he put the Tailed Beast in Rin. And Obito having the Sharingan made it easier to learn new techniques.

Comment: I don't have any cannon sources, but I think that the DNA thing you mentioned and the healing of the right side of his body probably has a lot to do with white Zetsu. Also, I am not sure Obito has Senju genetics, but Zetsu has Otsutsuki/Senju DNA. Also I see no reason that intense teaching from someone as powerful as Madara could not make someone grow exponentially more powerful over the course of two years.

Comment: Seems like two questions to me: probably should be split up as two in that case so you can get good answers and its not too broad.

Answer (score 2):

Obito had a part of zetsu attached to him , that explains the immense chakra to summon nine tails and also the height . 
When the cave collapsed and the boulder fell on obito ,half of his body was under it and the other half was not after which he decided to give kakashi his sharingan . From the manga-599 onwards upto 605 , we see the entire incident happen , from the cave collapsing to obito meeting madara for the first time , he is also not able to support his own weight and hence part of zetsu and attaches himself to him and they train together since the attachment is not entirely stable . 
Another reason for obito being able to summon the nine tails fox could be because he activated the mangekyou sharingan at such an early age .